# Error while accessing Activity option in Stack Exchange profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, error-message, 500-server-error

I am getting error page that stating "Oops something bad happened" when I click on Actity to see the graph in stackexchange profile.

[image]
I am getting this response page.

[image: Getting Response]

Comment: Reproed on my profile.

Comment: I'm getting this as well, for more than a day now. I can access the activity page on individual SE sites (at least the ones that I tried).

Comment: Seems to be fixed for my profile now.

Comment: Probably one of the bugs that come and go without much attention... :/

Comment: Yes this bug seems to be fixed now.. :)

Comment: No error, but it's [over caching now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196213/152859).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a edge error case where some json was being incorrectly parsed; the error shouldn't occur any longer.